# git svn fetch 'Error running context: Software caused connection abort at...'

Tags: git, svn, clone

A few months ago I GIT cloned a large SVN repository (6GB+, aprox. 10 branches, 3 years of daily logs). The clone took many hours to complete. It stopped several times and had to be continued with `git svn fetch`. Meanwhile the SVN to Git migration was put on hold as other projects became higher priority.

Fast forward to the present. I'm trying to bring the SVN clone up-to-date with the SVN changes of the past few months. When I run `git svn fetch` after about 10 minutes of fetching I get the following error:

`Software caused connection abort: Error running context: Software caused connection abort at C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.`

On the next `git svn fetch` I get an `Index Mismatch` error followed by 10 minutes of fetching (from the same point as before) followed by the error above. So it's stuck in a loop.

**Is it possible to bring the SVN clone up to date without doing a fresh clone** (as it is suggested in some stackOverflow answers)?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a bigger --log-window-size than the 100 default value?

Comment: Yes I have. And just tried one more time to make sure. I don't think the --log-window-size helps because for the 10 minutes that the fetching works it's on the same log. In fact it appears that it's fetching all files (irrespective of log). Perhaps the `Index Mismatch` error requires a full working copy fetch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was due to some single revisions being very large and taking over 10 minutes to download. They wouldn't finish before the Apache Server Timeout and cutting off the connection.

The solution was to set a higher server timeout in the SVN Server's `http.conf`

Simply appended `Timeout 1800` as suggested [here](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=539779).

Comment: This helped me. I had to increase it to 2300 in my case.